# BigQuery Client using Python | Timeout and Polling issues

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am trying to execute a SQL statement on BQ Database by initializing the BQ Client. This has been running smoothly for a while but lately seeing an issue.

My code specifically fails when its trying to wait for the results from the DB

```
query_job = client.query(QUERY)  # API request to start the query    
db_rslt = query_job.result()     # Wait for the query to return results
```

Here is error message:

`File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py", line xxx, in result super(QueryJob, self).result(retry=retry, timeout=timeout) File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/cloud/bigquery/job.py", line xxx, in result return super(_AsyncJob, self).result(timeout=timeout) File "/opt/conda/default/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/api_core/future/polling.py", line xxx, in result self._blocking_poll(timeout=timeout, retry=retry, polling=polling) TypeError: _blocking_poll() got an unexpected keyword argument 'retry'`

Added the timeout parameter to the result method but did not help

Comment: Versions of libraries?

Comment: @JohnHanley I am Sorry, can you please be little more specific about which libraries that you are point to and provide any pointers on how to check them. Thanks

Comment: `pip freeze` will print a list of installed Python packages and version information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

7 days ago Google released an [update](https://github.com/googleapis/python-api-core/releases/tag/v1.34.0) to `google-api-core==1.34.0` for bug fixes. I guess this introduced some breaking changes if you are not using the later versions of `google-cloud-bigquery`. You may either:

1. Pin `google-api-core` to the previous working version (eg. 1.33.2)
2. Upgrade `google-cloud-bigquery` to the latest versions.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the version of your installed google-cloud-bigquery library, if you are using a 1.x version, make sure to set google-api-core to a version less than 1.34.0.

What is actually happening here is that when you install google-cloud-bigquery, a bunch of other google related libraries are installed automatically with it, google-api-core is one of these libraries. However, a higher version is being installed thus causing this problem.

In my case, setting my google-api-core==1.33.2 solves the issue. Other solution would be is to upgrade google-cloud-bigquery to a later version .

Answer (score 2):

This did the trick for me, although I was having this issue on Kaggle notebooks:

```
pip install -U google-cloud-bigquery google-api-core==1.33.2
```

Also the v2 version of google-api-core seems to work:

```
google-api-core==2.11.0
```

https://github.com/googleapis/python-api-core/releaseshttps://github.com/googleapis/python-api-core/releases

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by changing the bigquery version to the latest: 'google-cloud-bigquery==3.4.0'.

Answer (score 0):

This also happened to me.
My python image is `3.8.13:bulleye`.
It was using the following stack of google library.

```
google-auth==1.33.0
google-cloud-bigquery==1.25.0
google-cloud-firestore==2.3.1
```

Changing them to

```
db-dtypes==1.0.0
google-auth==2.6.0
google-cloud-bigquery==3.0.1
google-cloud-firestore==2.5.3
```

solved the problems.

`db-dtypes` is required for new version of google cloud library.